# Time stamp class in org.apache.commons.net package

Tags: java, ntp

I want to use time stamp as part of my application(I am using JAVA).I was asked to use Network Time Protocol(NTP).I have searched in google and I was able to find a package "org.apache.commons.net"  where there is a TimeStamp class.I have gone through [this link](http://www.java-frameworks.com/java/commons/org/apache/commons/net/ntp/TimeStamp.java.html) to know more about the class.
What should I pass to the constructors of this class(what is the significance of each constructor). Actually TS class should return us the time stamp,instead it is asking to input time stamp.I am confused with that.

Comment: NTP is very unreliable on a sample basis (error can be over 10 ms even in ideal situations). It works best when taking many, many samples which is something the OS does.  The best arrangement is to have NTP setup properly on your machine and use you now "correct" system clock.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just ask the operating system for the current time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following overload of the constructor to create the TimeStamp Object.

```
   public TimeStamp(Date d)
```

pass an object of java.util.Date as argument.

This will give you a timestamp value which is represented as a
 64-bit unsigned fixed-point number in seconds relative to 0-hour on 1-January-1900.

The main significance is that it is a protocol, a standard followed by different systems. Different systems present in a network may not have their clock synchronized, and may not understand how others are measuring time, may follow different time zones. using NTP they synchronize their clock to UTC

Comment: DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
 Date now = new Date();
 TimeStamp ts=new TimeStamp(now); and I am using getTime method(which returns NTP time stamp as JAVA time)..Answer:1335425989552..Is it right??

Comment: absolutely right, if you check the source code of org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeStamp

 public long getTime()
    {
        return getTime(ntpTime);
    }

it returns the longmillisecods(which is same as java time)

Comment: Thanks,My problem is I need to calculate say X based on TS(uisng formula) value.Suppose at Client-value is X,at Server -X'.Both won't be equal.As per my algorithm I need to do verify placing X'-1,X'-2 in formula...Is there a chance that they both match??Is TS returned in millisec??Do I need to change into seconds??

Comment: well, im not sure what you are trying to do in your algorithm and cant tell if they will match without looking into it. The time returned by NTP TS is in seconds, you dont have to do any conversion

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static getCurrentTime() to get a timestamp that represents the current time measured to the nearest milliseconds:

```
Timestamp myTs = Timestamp.getCurrentTime();
```

Comment: I am getting Time stamp as "dd3437864.7eb851eb",how should I use this?